# Can not connect to PostgreSql server in docker container with psql remotely (locally from the docker host it works)

Tags: postgresql, docker, connection, psql, remote-access

I am pretty new with the topic and couldn't find any help so far. I have the PostgresSql eerver installed in a docker container. I can connect to it from inside the docker container with `psql -h /run/postgresql/ -U postgres` and from the host on that the container is run with `psql -h myServerName -U postgres`. I can not connect to the server from my computer remotely.

Sometimes psql terminates with an error, sometimes it jsut gets stuck with no response. In the case of an error message it is:

```
psql: Fehler: Verbindung zum Server auf »....de« (10.173.157.25), Port 5432 fehlgeschlagen: Server beendete die Verbindung unerwartet
        Das heißt wahrscheinlich, dass der Server abnormal beendete
        bevor oder während die Anweisung bearbeitet wurde.
```

It says basically, that the server has closed the connection unexpectedly and that it means that the server was terminated abnormaly bevore or while executing the request. That is not true since on the host I can see that the server is online.

The configuration in postgresql.conf is as following:

```
listen_addresses = '*'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                                        # (change requires restart)
port = 5432                             # (change requires restart)
```

The configuration in pg_hba.conf is:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
host    all             all             ::/0                    md5
```

The output on the host for the command `lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN` is:

```
docker-pr 31751 root    4u  IPv4 113219      0t0  TCP *:5432 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 31758 root    4u  IPv6 121217      0t0  TCP *:5432 (LISTEN)
```

I have verified the configuration of the server and the container serval times, but do not see the issue.
I am pretty lost with this issue, have been trying to get it work for days now without success. Interessting about the issue is, that I tried it a view weeks ago and it worked. Any usefull hint is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Is 'myServerName' the name of the docker host, or the name of the container?

Comment: It is the name of the host of the docker container.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with a firewall/router between your remote computer and your docker host.  I don't know why the issue doesn't present consistently.

Comment: I can access the host with SSH and I checked the protocol with TShark. For both cases the same protocol (TCP/IP -> PGSQL) but on my windows machine the psql just gets stuck for whatever reason.

Comment: But maybe you are right, on the host side I see pgsql package in both directions, on the client I see only the sent package. Does that make sense that a port is closed in one direction?

Comment: It sounds like maybe your client is behind a broken NAT.  The initial connection is allowed through, but the reply is not allowed back.  I've never seen that before.